# How to var dump each posts when moving to trash in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to show a list of posts inside a **var_dump**, this is the actual code:

```
function deleted_cpt_orders() {

    global $post_type, $post;

    if ( $post_type == 'cpt_orders' ) {

        var_dump($post);

    }

}
add_action( 'trashed_post', 'deleted_cpt_orders' );
```

If i delete only 1 post the `var_dump` is shown, but if i **delete 2 posts** or more the result is

```
NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`global $post` is supposed to hold a single post object. If you delete multiple objects, it won't be set. However, `trashed_post` hook passes `post id`, therefore, you can do the following

```
function deleted_cpt_orders($object_id)
{
    $post = get_post($object_id);
    if ($post->post_type == 'cpt_orders')
    {
        var_dump($post);
    }
}

add_action('trashed_post', 'deleted_cpt_orders');
```

Comment: Thanks! Now i understand that!

Comment: @IgorYavych - Out of interest, why are you using `$post` as  a variable when it's a global variable or is it only a global variable in some scenarios?

Comment: @Motivated in this particular scenario, $post is just a variable, since there is no `global $post` in this piece of code

Comment: @IgorYavych, out of interest, why use `$post` as a variable? Does it not introduce potential complexity in extending the code if `global $post` is referenced in the future?

Comment: No, it does not introduce any complexity and you're overthinking possible unlikely scenarios in this particular case